# Geometry basic problem

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles

If I have a triangle with given: $b-c=3 \space\text{cm}$, $a=6\space \text{cm}$ and $\alpha$ is $30^\circ$, how do I draw this? Please help me by telling me where I can find this type of exercises online with explanations. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Draw some generic triangle:

[image]

Then fill in what you know. $A=30\text{ degrees}$, $a=6\text{ cm}$ and $b-c=3\text{ cm}$. That means we can say $c=b-3\text{ cm}$

[image]

You can solve for $b$ using the Law of Cosines. Then from $b$ you can find $c$.

Comment: But how about if you were to just draw it without calculating anything?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to draw an accurate to-scale diagram? And not just a diagram like the second picture?

Comment: Something like that. Basically without calculating anything, just drawing it with compass and a set square.

Comment: @user137794 See my delayed reply. Hope it satisfies your requirement because your question did not specifically say where the alpha is between which two lines.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Step 1. Draw a line 3 units long (PQ).

Step 2. Draw another line 6 units long (PR) such that the angle between the two is 30 degrees.

(Hope that drawing a 30 degrees angle should not be a problem.)

Step 3. Join the endpoints of these two lines (QR).

Step 4. Produce the 3-unit line to certain extend (PQ... ).

Step 5. Draw MN, the perpendicular bisector of QR such that MN cuts the PQ produced at S.

Step 6. Join SR.

Triangle PRS is the required satisfying the given conditions (1) one side is 6; (2) one angle is 30 degrees (3) the difference between the other 2 sides is 3.